# return data in original order in aggregate function

Tags: r, aggregate-functions

I had a look at some of the answers already provided but they didn't really work for me. I'm trying to aggregate a data set (from hourly to daily values) using aggregate function.
I used the following:

```
agg <- aggregate(sapply(original_data[,3:4], as.numeric) ~ date, data = original_data, mean, na.rm = T)
```

It worked in a manner of speaking, i.e. the resulting daily means are correct, but it returns a data frame with the day order mixed, for example my date format is a single column in YYYY.MM.D format (example 2000.1.1 for Jan 1st 2000), but in the output data frame months run 1, 12, 2, 3, 4, and days run 1, 10, 11 etc instead of the expected order.

It seems really strange and I have no idea why this would happen. Is there a simple way to make sure the function returns data in its original order?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr::arrange()`:

```
agg <- dplyr::arrange(aggregate(sapply(original_data[,3:4], as.numeric) ~ date, data = original_data, mean, na.rm = T), as.Date(date))
```

The reason your dates are being arranged as you describe is because they are not of `class` `Date`. You can check this by running `class(original_data$date)`.

Here's an example using sample data:

```
original_data <- data.frame(date = c("2020-01-01", "2020-10-01", "2020-12-01", "2020-2-01"),
                            number1 = c(5, 10, 23, 10),
                            number2 = c(40, 50, 60, 70))
```

###### When you arrange dates as `character`:

```
aggregate(sapply(original_data[,2:3], as.numeric) ~ date, data = original_data, mean, na.rm = T)
```

###### When you arrange dates as `date`:

```
dplyr::arrange(aggregate(sapply(original_data[,2:3], as.numeric) ~ date, data = original_data, mean, na.rm = T), as.Date(date))
```

Comment: Great. With a bit of tinkering that worked. Thanks.